# Does the Gordian distance depend on the chosen link diagram?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $K,L:S^1\rightarrow S^3$ be two knots. The Gordian distance between $K$ and $L$ is defined to be the minimum number of crossing changes to convert a knot diagram of $K$ to a knot diagram of $L$. Further I understand this definition as taking the minimum over all such knot diagrams of $K$. However the question arises whether or not the Gordian distance does depend on the chosen knot diagram.
More precisely: Does the Gordian distance change under Reidemeister moves?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do I have this right? You're considering knot diagrams for $K$ such that changing some subset of crossings yields a diagram for $L$, you're defining the Gordian distance with respect to a diagram to be the least number of crossings in that diagram that need to be changed, and you're defining the Gordian distance between two knots to be the minimum Gordian distance with respect to all such diagrams? I would be very surprised if Gordian distance with respect to diagrams were constant over all such diagrams.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to define Gordian distance in terms of diagrams. By a transversality argument, smooth paths in $C^\infty(S^1,S^3)$ (as smooth maps $S^1\times [0,1]\to S^3$) can be approximated by smooth paths that for all but finitely many $t$ are smooth embeddings (i.e., knots), and at those singular $t$ there is a single point of self-intersection locally modeled as a pair of intersecting lines that pass through each other as $t$ changes. Gordian distance between two knots is the minimum number of such singular $t$ over all such paths.

Comment: Yes you are right! The Gordian distance does depend on the chosen diagram. I think I got really confused yesterday..
Your definition of Gordian distance indeed is elegant! Thank you!